# What is the need for using only a stable sorting algorithm for Radix sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am trying to understand the danger in using an unstable sorting algorithm(like Quick sort) in Radix sort.
Also, is stable algorithm must in both cases(i.e.,MSD Radix sort and LSD Radix sort)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with *will do the job*? If you mean the output will be sorted, then please realise that Radix sort on MSD (stable/unstable) will also do the job. If you mean the algorithm will be stable, then why do you say *any(stable/unstable)* will do the job, because obviously an unstable algorithm is not stable? What is the *job* you are speaking of?

Comment: After reading your comment, I realized the ambiguity in my question. Also, I realized that my understanding of Radix sort was not entirely right. I have edited the description.

Comment: OK, what do you mean with *is stable algorithm must*: I don't understand the word *must* in this context.

Comment: By "must" I mean whether a stable algorithm has to be used in both cases to ensure that the original ordering of equal elements is preserved in the output. I want to know if using an unstable sorting algorithm(algorithm that has the potential to change ordering of equal elements in the output)  can be used in any one of the cases and we would still be guaranteed of desired output(ordering preserved).

Comment: So you are asking whether an algorithm has to be stable in order to preserve the original ordering or equal elements. But that is the ***definition*** of stable. If an algorithm is stable, it preserves the order of equal elements, if an algorithm is unstable, it does not guarantee to preserve that order. I don't understand what you are asking. But oh well, you already accepted an answer... so I'll move on ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSD radix sort is usually not practical, as the virtual bins can not be concatenated after each pass. If sorting by 8 bit bytes, after the first pass you have 256 separate bins, after two passes, 65536 bins, after three passes, 16777216 bins, ... .

Update - one exception to this is doing just one MSD pass to split up a large array into 256 (or 512 or 1024 or ...) bins, with the goal that each bin will fit in cache. This assumes somewhat uniform distribution so that the bins are similar in size. After the initial pass, then each bin is sorted using LSD passes, which could be done with multiple threads (if 4 cores, then LSD sort 4 bins at at time using 4 threads), since there would be no collision issues between the bins.

LSD radix sort needs to be stable, since the virtual bins are concatenated in order and the following passes on the more significant "digits" need to retain the order established by the prior passes. Note that LSD radix sort is how the old card sorters dating back to the early 1900's operated.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_card_sorter#Earlier_sorters

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good start to give two minutes to the history.

Radix sort is the algorithm used by the card-sorting machines you now find only in
computer museums. The cards have 80 columns, and in each column, a machine can
punch a hole in one of 12 places. The sorter can be mechanically “programmed”
to examine a given column of each card in a deck and distribute the card into one
of 12 bins depending on which place has been punched. An operator can then
gather the cards bin by bin, so that cards with the first place punched are on top of
cards with the second place punched, and so on.
For decimal digits, each column uses only 10 places. (The other two places
are reserved for encoding numeric characters.) A d-digit number would then
occupy a field of d columns. Since the card sorter can look at only one column
at a time, the problem of sorting n cards on a d-digit number requires a sorting
algorithm.
Intuitively, you might sort numbers on their most significant digit, sort each of
the resulting bins recursively, and then combine the decks in order. Unfortunately,
since the cards in 9 of the 10 bins must be put aside to sort each of the bins, this
procedure generates many intermediate piles of cards that you would have to keep
track of. (See Exercise 8.3-5.)
Radix sort solves the problem of card sorting—counterintuitively—by sorting on
the least significant digit first. The algorithm then combines the cards into a single
deck, with the cards in the 0 bin preceding the cards in the 1 bin preceding the
cards in the 2 bin, and so on. Then it sorts the entire deck again on the second-least
significant digit and recombines the deck in a like manner. The process continues
until the cards have been sorted on all d digits. Remarkably, at that point, the cards
are fully sorted on the d-digit number. Thus, only d passes through the deck are
required to sort. Figure 8.3 shows how radix sort operates on a “deck” of seven
3-digit numbers.
In order for radix sort to work correctly, the digit sorts must be stable. The sort
performed by a card sorter is stable, but the operator has to be wary about not
changing the order of the cards as they come out of a bin, even though all the cards
in a bin have the same digit in the chosen column.

```
                                                                        -by CLRS
```

From the article, you may get that, MSD radix sort is not feasible.

and

for the need of stable digit sorting algo,  let's try to understand with an example

assume a list to be sorted

21, 52, 35, 76, 49, 55, 51, 34, 31, 39

sort the number using digit at once place.

(21, 51, 31,) (52,) (34,) (35, 55,) (76,) (49, 39)  <---- this is what when we use stable sort to sort once digit.

But if we use unstable sorting algo to sort once digit, then values within the parenthesis can be interchanged with each other.

can be like
(31, 51, 21,) (52,) (34,) (35, 55,) (76,) (49, 39) <----- this order will not affect the final result

let's sort this w.r.t. digit at tenth place

(21,) (31, 34, 35, 39,) (49,) (51, 52, 55,) (76)<----this will be the (final)output if we use stable sort for digit sorting.

if digit sort is not stable then the output may not be sored order.

like this
(21,) (39, 35, 39, 31) (49,) (52, 51, 55,) (76)